# Pyspark: change values in an array column based on another array column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following pyspark dataframe:

```
root
 |-- tokens: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- posTags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- dependencies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- labelledDependencies: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

with an example of the following data

```
+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|tokens                        |posTags                    |dependencies                       |labelledDependencies                        |
+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|[i, try, to, get, my, balance]|[NNP, VB, TO, VB, PRP$, NN]|[try, ROOT, get, try, balance, get]|[nsubj, root, mark, parataxis, appos, nsubj]|
+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I want to change the labelled dependency of the token balance from nsubj to dobj.

My logic is as follows:
if you find a labelled dependency `nsubj` and the token has `POS` Tag `NN` and the token has dependency on a token that has `POS` tag `VB` (get) then change `nsubj` to `dobj`.

I can do this with the following function:

```
def change_things(tokens,posTags,dependencies,labelledDependencies):
    for i in range(0,len(labelledDependencies)):
        if labelledDependencies[i] == 'nsubj':
            if posTags[i] == 'NN':
                if posTags[tokens.index(dependencies[i])] == 'VB':
                    labelledDependencies[i] = 'dobj'
    return tokens,posTags,dependencies,labelledDependencies
```

and maybe even register it as a udf.

However, my question is how I can do this without using a udf and instead only pyspark built-in methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spark built-in [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform) function :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "labelledDependencies",
    F.expr("""transform(
            labelledDependencies, 
            (x, i) -> CASE WHEN x = 'nsubj' 
                                AND posTags[i] = 'NN' 
                                AND posTags[array_position(tokens, dependencies[i]) - 1] = 'VB' 
                           THEN 'dobj'
                           ELSE x
                      END
        )
    """)
)



df2.show(1, False)
#+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
#|tokens                        |posTags                    |dependencies                       |labelledDependencies                       |
#+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
#|[i, try, to, get, my, balance]|[NNP, VB, TO, VB, PRP$, NN]|[try, ROOT, get, try, balance, get]|[nsubj, root, mark, parataxis, appos, dobj]|
#+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. What does `AND posTags[array_position(tokens, dependencies[i]) - 1]` this do exactly?

Comment: @romborimba it is equivalent to the condition `if posTags[tokens.index(dependencies[i])] == 'VB'` in your code. `i` is the index of the current element in `labelledDependencies` array.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear. Final question, how would I go if I wanted to create a new column and not transform an existing one?

Comment: @romborimba just rename it ;) `df.withColumn("labelledDependencies_v2", ...)`